# Why am I getting different addresses when using similar logic to increment two different pointer types?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I don't understand why the addresses of my floats go up by 16, when the size of my floats are 4. Could someone please explain?

Code:

```
char* mychar   = new char[SIZE];
float* myfloat = new float[SIZE];

for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    mychar[i] = 'A' + i;
    myfloat[i] = 101 + i; 
}

for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(12) << "new char @ <"  << static_cast<void*>(mychar) + sizeof(char)*i  << ">=<" << mychar[i]  << ">" 
             << setw(14) << "   new float @ <" << myfloat + sizeof(float)*i                    << ">=<" << myfloat[i] << ">\n"; 
    }

cout<< "Size of float: " << sizeof(float) << endl << "Size of char: " << sizeof(char);
```

Output:

```
new char @ <0x800102e8>=<A>   new float @ <0x800102f8>=<101>
new char @ <0x800102e9>=<B>   new float @ <0x80010308>=<102>
new char @ <0x800102ea>=<C>   new float @ <0x80010318>=<103>
new char @ <0x800102eb>=<D>   new float @ <0x80010328>=<104>
Size of float: 4
Size of char: 1
```

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this........... baffling

Comment: Because pointer arithmetic works in terms of units, not bytes.

Comment: @Andrey Perhaps because it's an obvious duplicate? (I've seen at least two identical questions asked this week.)

Comment: @DominikC No, just `myfloat + i`.

Comment: @H2CO3 fair, I haven't but I believe you.  Although I will say this is not in the category of questions that are trivially easy to search for, especially for a beginner.  If you know the phrase "pointer arithmetic" then you know the answer to this already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Pointer Arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713929/c-pointer-arithmetic)

Comment: @H2CO3 Is my output correct then?

Comment: @jameswoo Yes. While you're a beginner, the compiler is never wrong.

Comment: @jameswoo the reason is that when you add 1 to a pointer, it does not increment the memory address by 1, but by `sizeof(type of object pointed to)`.  See the link H2CO3 posted.

Comment: See what happens when you simply myfloat + 1 on different types.

Comment: @Andrey Yup, but one could just search for it without the exact term too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that `myfloat` is a `float*`. This means that if you write an expression like

```
myfloat + n
```

the result will be a pointer to the `float` that is `n` positions down in the array of `float`s whose address starts at `myfloat`. In other words, adding `n` here will automatically increment the pointer by `n * sizeof(float)` bytes, since pointer addition is aware of the size of the object.

Consequently, if you write

```
myfloat + n * sizeof(float)
```

you are not jumping forward by `n * sizeof(float)` bytes, but rather than `n * sizeof(float) * sizeof(float)` bytes, which happens to be 16n bytes.

Hope this helps!