# Why doesn't malloc allocate enough memory?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am really stuck with one very simple piece of code.
This program takes argument like `./a.out -t=1,32,45,2` and prints quantity of commas in stdout. But from time to time execution works correctly and and more often throws segmentation fault.

I figured out that problem in this line of function `substr_cnt` (I also placed corresponding commentaries in code below):

`target_counting = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(target)));`

In fact malloc returns NULL. If I change `sizeof(char)` by `sizeof(char *)` all starts work like a charm but I can't understand why is that. Furthermore in main function I also use malloc, and even with the same line

`arg_parameter = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(argv[1] - 3)));`

all works just fine.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define strindex(target, source) ((size_t) strstr(target, source) - (size_t) target)

int substr_cnt( char *target, char *source ) {
    int i=0;
    int cnt=0;
    char *target_counting;
    //this is NOT working
    target_counting = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(target)));
    //this is working
    //target_counting = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *)*(strlen(target)));

    if (target_counting == NULL) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    strcpy(target_counting, target);
    while ((i=strindex(target_counting, source)) > 0) {
        strncpy(target_counting, target_counting + i + 1, strlen(target_counting));
        cnt++;
    }
    free(target_counting);
    return cnt;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int i;
    int default_behavior = 0;
    int arg_parametr_cnt;
    char *arg_parameter; 
    if (argc == 1) {
        default_behavior = 1;
    } else if (argv[1][0] == '-' && argv[1][1] == 't' && argv[1][2] == '=') {
        //this is working
        arg_parameter = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(argv[1] - 3)));
        strncpy(arg_parameter, argv[1]+3, strlen(argv[1]));
        printf("%s\n", arg_parameter);
        arg_parametr_cnt = substr_cnt(arg_parameter, ",");
        printf("commas: %d\n", arg_parametr_cnt);
    }
    else {
        printf("wrong command line");
        return 1;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should be aware that strncpy does not guarantee to include a null terminator.  That's part of why your program crashes.

Comment: I don't think you wanted to this: `strlen(argv[1] - 3)` in `malloc` in `main()`. it should be `strlen(argv[1]) - 3` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues here, the main point, you don't need to allocate memory at all. You can implement searching for a given substring without modifying the string and therefore work directly on the given `argv` parameters, e.g.

```
int substr_cnt(const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    const char *found = haystack;
    while ((found = strstr(found, needle)) != NULL) {
        ++found;
        ++cnt;
    }

    return cnt;
}
```

Same for the call in `main`, just pass `argv` directly

```
arg_parametr_cnt = substr_cnt(argv[1] + 3, ",");
```

Now to answer your question, unless you really see the output of

```
printf("malloc failed\n");
```

I don't believe, `malloc` returns `NULL`, because when you allocate an even larger amount of memory, `sizeof(char*)` vs `sizeof(char)`, it works.

The reasons, why your program crashes, are already covered in the other answers. To summarize

- `target_counting = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(target)));` allocates one char less than it should
- `while ((i=strindex(target_counting, source)) > 0)` I'm not sure, what happens, when the result of `strstr` is `NULL`. `strindex` *might* return a negative number, depending on your memory layout, but I am not sure.
- `strncpy(target_counting, target_counting + i + 1, strlen(target_counting));` This is not really an issue, but since you copy the rest of the string, you could use `strcpy(target_counting, target_counting + i + 1)` instead.
- `arg_parameter = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(argv[1] - 3)));` this should be `malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(argv[1]) - 3 + 1)`
- `strncpy(arg_parameter, argv[1]+3, strlen(argv[1]));` again `strcpy(arg_parameter, argv[1]+3)` would be sufficient

*Update:*

In this version

```
int strindex(char *target, char *source)
{
    char *idx;
    if ((idx = strstr(target, source)) != NULL) {
        return idx - target;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

you have an explicit test for `NULL` and act accordingly.

In the macro version

```
#define strindex(target, source) ((size_t) strstr(target, source) - (size_t) target)
```

there is no such test. You determine the index by calculating the difference between `strstr()` and the base address `target`. This is fine so far, but what happens, when `strstr()` returns `NULL`?

Pointer arithmetic is defined with two pointers, pointing into the same array. As soon as the two pointers point into different arrays, or one pointing into an array and the other somewhere else, the behaviour is undefined.

Technically, when you calculate `NULL - target`, it *might* yield a negative value, but it also might not. If `target` points to the address of `0x0f0a3a90`, you could have `0x0 - 0x0f0a3a90` and get a negative value. If `target` points to `0xfe830780` however, it might be interpreted as a negative number, and then `0x0 - 0xfe830780` could result in a positive number.

But the main point is, you have undefined behaviour. For further reading look for *pointer arithmetic*, e.g. [C++: Pointer Arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11713929/1741542)

Comment: As it turned out, main problem was in my macros, just translated it to function, and all works now.

`int strindex( char *target, char *source ) {
     char *idx;
     if ((idx = strstr(target, source)) != NULL) {
         return idx - target;
     } else {
         return -1;
     }
}`

Comment: But honestly I still don't understand fully, why is that.

Answer (score 2):

your malloc is not allocating space for the null terminator, you need to malloc (strlen(string)+1).
The malloc with a char* works because a pointer (is normal) 4 bytes long, so you are allocating 4 times more memory than required - minus the 1 byte need for a null terminator.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may lie here: `malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(argv[1] - 3))` in `main`. You are subtracting `3` from `argv[1]`. 
I think you intended to use:

`malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(argv[1]) - 2));  // Allocate one more space for '\0' character`

Doing this makes `strlen` to access unallocated memory.

Your program may not fail here, but later, because it is simply `undefined behavior`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several buffer overruns, but I think that the bug that makes you program crash is the following:

```
    strncpy(target_counting, target_counting + i + 1, strlen(target_counting));
```

**Note that the strings in strncpy may not overlap!**

I suggest that you do a memmove instead, because memmove can handle overlapping buffers:

```
    memmove(target_counting, target_counting + i + 1, strlen(target_counting + i + 1) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your main issue is here :

```
 arg_parameter = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(argv[1] - 3)));
```

especially here

```
 strlen(argv[1] - 3)
```

you pass to `strlen` address of `argv[1]-3` which is not valid address.
actually what you meant is `strlen(argv[1]) - 3`. As others said you also should add one char for `\0` so `strlen(argv[1]) - 2`