# Why is this method for navigating through an array wrong?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to understand C pointers, I set up the following example:

```
int main()
{
    int temp[] = {45,67,99};    
    int* address;
    address = &temp[0]; //equivalent to address = temp;
    std::cout << "element 0: " << *address << std::endl;
    address = (address + sizeof(int));
    std::cout << "element 1: " << *address << std::endl;

    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the first element is printed correctly while the second one is garbage. I know that I can just use:

```
address = (address + 1);
```

in order to move the pointer to the second element of the array, but I don't understand why the first method is wrong.

Comment: If you know that `address = (address + 1);` is right, then why do you expect `address = (address + sizeof(int));` to be right, too? Of course you get a different result when you add a different number.

Comment: The previous 6 questions on c++ have been downvoted to oblivion. Someone is going on a downvoting spree.

Comment: If you wanted to actually advance `sizeof(int)` *bytes*, that pointer should have been casted to `char *` and then advanced by `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen because i couldnt' see the difference between the two

Comment: @DevinLiu multiple downvotes require multiple people willing to sacrifice rep to express their displeasure with the question. Usually this is a sign of a weak question. Runs of multiple downvotes suggests nothing more than a run of weak questions.

Comment: Just printing out `sizeof(int)` might have helped then. Btw, no need to approve every edit proposed on your posts, that last one made it way worse.

Comment: @baummitAugen ok, i will remember your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: @user4581301 You don’t lose rep for downvoting questions, only answers. And at least in its current state, this question doesn’t seem to deserve nearly as low a score as it has.

Comment: @DanielH Did not know that. I'll have to start downvoting more questions. Muhuhahahahahaha! The monster is unleashed! But seriously folks, I think I'll stick to my current downvoting strategy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incrementing a pointer by N will not increment it by `N` bytes, but by `N * sizeof(pointed_type)` bytes.

So when you do:

```
address = (address + sizeof(int));
```

You are incrementing the address by (probably) 4 times the size of int, which is past your original array.

What you intended to do is:

```
address = reinterpret_cast<int*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(address) + sizeof(int));
```

Which is pretty horrendous.

Comment: @Ron When you cast to `char*` advancing the pointer moves 1 byte at a time. Then after moving the correct number of bytes, you cast back to `int*` so the new address is interpreted correctly during the dereference operation.

Comment: @Ron I interpreted the asker's question as "I wanted to increment the pointer by a number of bytes, why can't I do that?" I showed him how to accomplish his intent.

Answer (score 6):

The operator [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) returns the size of the object in bytes. So (depending on your compiler) you may have just done

```
address + sizeof(int) == address + 4
```

This will obviously access out of bounds when you dereference the pointer. The problem is that the way you are trying to use `sizeof` is *already accounted for* in the [pointer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713929/c-pointer-arithmetic). When you add an integral (e.g. `1`) to an `int*` it already knows to move `1 int` over to the next address.

Answer (score 1):

An array is a group of elements of the Same Type mapped consecutively in memory one-next to the other.

The size of the array is:

```
sizeof(any element) * the number of elements
```

So the vice-vers to get the number of elements of an array you can:

```
Number of elements = sizeof(array) / sizeof(any element).
```

- These elements are addressable and each one is addressed with the first byte's address.

  ```
  int a[] = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000};
  std::cout << sizeof(int) << std::endl; // 4
  std::cout << sizeof(a) << std::endl; // 20: 5 * 4
  ```
- The addresses:

  ```
  cout << &a[0] << " : " << &a[1] << " : " <<
      &a[2] << " : " << &a[3] << endl;
  ```
- The outPut:

  ```
  0018FF38 : 0018FF3C : 0018FF40 : 0018FF44
  ```

As you can see the address is incrementing by sizeof(int) // 4

- To do it on your way:

  ```
  for(int* tmp = array; tmp <= a + nElement; tmp++)
      cout << tmp << " : ";
  ```

The result:

```
    0018FF38 : 0018FF3C : 0018FF40 : 0018FF44
```

As you can see the result is identical.

- To move from one element to another just increment / decrement the address as I did above:

  ```
  tmp++; // incrementing the address by 1 means moving to the next element, element means an integer which means 4 bytes. 1 here is not a single byte but a unit or element which is 4 byte here;
  ```
- To move to the n-element just:

  ```
  tmp += n;
  ```

In your example:

```
    address = (address + sizeof(int)); : 
    address = address + 4; // moving  to the 0 + 4 element which means fifth element (here outbound).
```